# Нет доступа в интернет в UBUNTU

Tags: настройка

Инет раздаётся через Ideco (компьютер другой), добавил туда комп с Убунту, в Убунту вбил мак и адрес ip4, указанный в настройках локальный шлюз работает/пингуется, а второй, через который собсно идёт инет - нет. Хотя в винде с аналогичными настройками всё пашет, в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: Сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой. [ссылка]( user.hashcode.ru/questions/2289/ubuntu-не-выходит-в-интернет).  
Я так и не понял почему все это происходит, но кто-то мне сказал, что возможно венда конфликтует Каким-то образом с убунту не поделив железо.  
Проблема у меня решилась, когда у меня полетел жесткий диск и я сначала установил убунту на новый жесткий диск, а потом венду. После этого в обоих ОС стал работать интернет. До полета на жесткий сначала устанавливалась венда, а потом убунту.

Comment: Убунту ставилось как раз для сноса винды, т.к. на неё не было лицензии, так что ставить винду не вариант. Кстати, раньше инет на нём пахал, временно давали доступ, не помню какие настройки были, кажется айпишник другой стоял.